# PHP, fopen, Browser Compatibility – What can it be

Tags: php, cross-browser, fopen, fread

On this page http://www.effectivewebsolutions.biz/video-spokesmodel.html if you put in your URL it opens it through fopen function and puts a video spokes-model on the website for demonstration purposes, here is the script.

```
<?php
$handle = fopen($_POST["url"], "r");

while($data = fread($handle, 1000000)){
    $contents .= $data;
}

fclose($handle);

echo "<base href=\"{$_POST['url']}\">";
echo "\n\n";
echo "<!-- Begin inserted page -->";
echo "\n";
echo $contents;
echo "\n";
echo "<!-- End inserted page -->";
echo "\n\n";
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.internet-spokesmodels.com/scripts/swfobject.js"></script>';
echo '<style type="text/css" media="screen">object { outline:none; } </style>';
echo "\n";
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.internet-spokesmodels.com/actors/script/SabrinaEXAMPLESredshirt_350x500.js"></script>';
?>
```

However in Safari it only opens text version of the website (no css or images).
It doesn’t make sense why would browser make a difference in this case.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I'm watching some attractive girl walk around on top of the contents of `/etc/passwd`. Please sanitize your input. As it stands I can read any file on the server.

Comment: why not use curl functionality?

Comment: btw, it's working in my version of safari, 5.0.3

Comment: @meager: Sadly accessing `etc/shadow` does not work...

Comment: Any one know whats wrong. It also doesn't work in chrome

Comment: @Ross Seriously dude, after 5 minutes of poking around **I have access to your database username/password**. You should take this down **now**.

Comment: @Ross You can punch *any file* into that box, and it will spit the contents out. I fished around and found your `wp-config.php` file. I can see its contents. This is bad. You should take the page offline until you've fixed it.

Comment: @meagar what would be a good / secure alternative to fopen

Comment: @Ross: You need to necessarily change `fopen` to something else. You need to sanitise the input. A simple `if (substr($url, 0, 4) != 'http')) some error...` would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the page does not render valid HTML. When I tried it with `http://www.google.ca`, I got:

```
<base href="http://google.ca">

<!-- Begin inserted page -->
<!doctype html><html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" ...
```

The DOCTYPE should be the first thing in the page, followed by a `<html>` tag with HTML content. The `<base>` tag should be within the `<head>` tag.

You can't blame Safari for displaying invalid HTML incorrectly.

Comment: @Ross just because the html of the pulled in page is valid, doesn't mean what you're outputting to the browser is valid.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code being returned should be identical across browsers, since browsers have nothing to do with server-side code. Check the validity of HTML. Also, sanitize your input as suggested meagar.

Comment: Exactly. The validity of HTML should be fine because its pulling an existing working site.

Comment: What does this mean "sanitize your input as suggested meagar"